# counting values in an update statement postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql, update

I have a repetitive method I want to execute and I expected underneath script to work. I found out the count() function is not allowed in postgres update statements. What is the most logical and simple way to update my column with the count of occurences I encounter, without creating a new table.

```
UPDATE
     table1 as tbl1
SET
     new_column = count(tbl2.*)
FROM
     table2 as tbl2
WHERE 
     ST_Intersects(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geopunt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT tbl1.geom, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2
  WHERE ST_Intersects(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geopunt)
  GROUP BY tbl1.geom 
)
UPDATE table1 tbl1 
SET new_column=t.cnt 
FROM t
WHERE tbl1.geom=t.geom
```